# Inverse of a sum of symmetric matrices

Tags: matrices

How can I proof this result? $$ X(X+Y)^{-1}Y=(X^{-1} +Y^{-1})^{-1} $$ where $X$, $ Y$, $(X+Y)$, and $(X^{-1} +Y^{-1})$  are symmetric and invertible matrices,each one with dimensions $p\times p$.

Comment: Have you tried multiplying the left hand side by $(X^{-1}+Y^{-1})$ ?

Comment: You of course need to assume $X,Y$ are invertible. Symmetry is not important here.

Comment: @LinAlgMan And also $X+Y$ and $X^{-1}+Y^{-1}$ ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We have

$$(X(X+Y)^{-1}Y)^{-1}=Y^{-1}(X+Y)X^{-1}=Y^{-1}XX^{-1}+Y^{-1}YX^{-1}\\=Y^{-1}+X^{-1}
$$

and the result follows.

Answer (score 3):

For number you have
$$ \frac{1}{x^{-1} + y^{-1}} = \frac{xy}{y+x}$$

For matrices, let $Z = X^{-1} + Y^{-1}$, I want to show that $X(X+Y)^{-1}Y Z = I$.

$$ X(X+Y)^{-1}Y ( X^{-1} + Y^{-1} ) = X(X+Y)^{-1}YX^{-1} + X(X+Y)^{-1}YY^{-1} = $$
$$ =  X(X+Y)^{-1}(YX^{-1} + I)  = X(X+Y)^{-1}(YX^{-1} + I)XX^{-1} = $$
$$ =  X(X+Y)^{-1}(Y + X)X^{-1}) = XX^{-1} = I$$