# Product of two multivariate Gaussian pdfs - normalizing constant

Tags: matrices, normal-distribution

https://www.cs.nyu.edu/~roweis/notes/gaussid.pdf contains expressions (p.2, 6e, 6f) for the normalization constant for the product of two multivariate Gaussian pdfs, with mean vectors $a$ and $b$ respectively, and covariance matrices $A$ and $B$ respectively. The product has mean $c$ and covariance matrix $C$. To simplify the notation, I'm writing here only the exponent for the normalization factor, and ignore the -1/2:

$a^TA^{-1}a+b^TB^{-1}b-c^TC^{-1}c$

Another source, http://www.gaussianprocess.org/gpml/chapters/RWA.pdf, gives the following equation for the same:  (page 200, A.8):

$(a-b)^T(A+B)^{-1}(a-b)$

After a number of failed attempts to derive the latter from the former, I think I'm missing a point somewhere.

Is there a straightforward solution?  Any hint that could help?  Or any source available on the web with the derivation?

Comment: If $X,Y, ZY$ are _independent_ multivariate Gaussian random variables, the the _joint_ density of $(X,Y,Z)$ is  the product of their densities. The expression $a^TA^{-1}a+b^TB^{-1}b+c^TC^{-1}c$ together with the fact that $\exp(x)\exp(y)\exp(z) = \exp(x+y+z)$ suggests that three multivariate Gaussian densities are being multiplied together.

Comment: @Dilip Sarwate  Thank you.  I had made a sign error in the first formula - this has just been corrected.  Actually the question refers to the case where two different Gaussian densities (for the same random vector) get multiplied.  The result is a third Gaussian density for that vector, multiplied with a scaling factor (referred to in the given sources as normalization constant, although I believe calling it reciproke of the normalization constant would be more intuitive, but I may be wrong).  The formulas given above are for the exponent of this scaling factor (-1/2 ignored).

Comment: @ Dilip Sarwate FYI - think I found a way - see the answer given, it may not be the shortest or most elegant one, though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to first expand the right summand in the first equation - i.e. perform the vector-matrix multiplications.

Then modify the result using for example the identity given here:
[Inverse of a sum of symmetric matrices](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/934921/inverse-of-a-sum-of-symmetric-matrices).

Further modify using the matrix inversion theorem (here a special case:  $U=V=I$) - it's actually shown on the next page of one of the sources given in the question:http://www.gaussianprocess.org/gpml/chapters/RWA.pdf, p.201 1st paragraph)

What one is left with after further rearranging and simplifying is the second equation plus the two left summands of the first equation - so plugging this result into the first equation and performing the subtractions gives the second equation (times -1, which had been ignored here).